# Wordpress - Format a post meta (date)

Tags: php, wordpress, meta

I want to display the date of an event on Revolution Slider. 
I managed to display the date using the meta slug, but I don't like its format.

I have no idea where to start ! 
I thought of, maybe creating another post meta with my desired date format, that would update when the first date meta is updated, but it seems a bit overkill ?

I have this code to add another meta and update it with the desired format : **but is there a better way ?**

```
function kia_convert_content(){
    $events = get_posts(array('numberposts'=>-1,'post_type'=>'pec_events'));

    foreach( $events as $post ) : setup_postdata($post); 

    // get old meta
    $mauvais_format = get_post_meta($post->ID,'pec_date', true); 

    // format date
    date_format($mauvais_format, 'j F Y');

    //add or update new meta
    if(metadata_exists('post', $post_id, 'l2v_pec_date')){
        update_post_meta($post->ID,'new_pec_date',$bon_format);
    }else{
        add_post_meta($post->ID, 'new_pec_date', $bon_format, true)
    }

    endforeach;

}
```

Comment: What do you mean you "don't like its format"? What *would* you like? It is very difficult to help some when we don't know what they want :-)

Comment: The format by default is something like 2017-08-25 17:30:00 which is good for computers but not really easy to read as human. I would like something like "25 august 2017"

Comment: Yes, adding another date to the meta is overkill. Can you show us the code where you display the date in the front end?

Comment: I display it directly on Revolution Slider using {{meta:_event_start_date}}. (I ended up switching plugin to Events Manager but still encounter the same problem)

Comment: Ok, the only options I see are either to use the API to hook into the "onload" event, or some custom javascript to replace the dates. So I guess its a matter of deciding if you prefer to do it client side or server side!